# How do I use function arguments in child switch statements?

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

In this case, I'm trying to call `shoppingClickHandler(buyItem)` expecting it to run the child `switch` statement to assign `feature` as `buyItem`.

However I am returned the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: buyItem is not defined`.

Should I just send strings to the function?

```
function shoppingClickHandler(feature){
    var msg;
    var itemIdentifier = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    switch(feature) {

        case buyItem: msg = "You bought Item #" + itemIdentifier;
        break;

        case tryItem: msg = "You tried Item #" + itemIdentifier + " on";
        break;

        case suggestItem: msg = "You suggested Item #" + itemIdentifier;
        break;

        case giftItem: msg = "You gifted Item #" + itemIdentifier;
        break;

        case add_to_wishlist: msg = "You added Item #" + itemIdentifier + " to your wishlist";
        break;
    }
    makeEntry(msg);
}


//Buy button test
$('.buy').click(function(){
    shoppingClickHandler(buyItem);
})

//Try button test
$('.try').click(function(){

})

//Suggest button test
$('.suggest').click(function(){

})

//Gifting button test
$('.gift').click(function(){

})

//Add to wisthlist test
$('.add_to_wishlist').click(function(){

})
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for _strings_.

Comment: `buyItem` _is_ undefined.  Unless you haven't posted the whole code, no where in that example do you defined a variable called `buyItem`.  If you meant to have the function check a string, make sure to add single or double quotes around the argument when calling the shoppingClickHandler function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use as string

```
  case 'buyItem':
  //ets...
```